# How to in the debugger of the Visual Studio 2015 watch a http request and response?

Tags: visual-studio, http

Could you please tell me, how to watch in the debugger of the Visual Studio 2015 http requests and responses of my winform application which uses the Internet?

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Visual Studio, but if you are looking for a generic way to do this, I use Fiddler. http://www.telerik.com/fiddler

Comment: ok, thanks for Fiddler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common tool used to monitor web traffic for debugging purposes is [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler).  And it's free.  It does not integrate with Visual Studio however.

You can also use the `F12` tools for your favorite browser (IE, Edge, Chrome, and FireFox).